# Gnuplot: how to use type-1 font in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, gnuplot

Gnuplot 4.6.5.

Gnuplot generate pdf files with True Type fonts by default, more specifically True Type (CID) fonts.

I have problem in processing the generated PDF file using Ghostscript because it has CID fonts. How can I use type 1 fonts in the PDF and get ride of CID fonts?

Here is a test script:

```
set term pdfcairo
set output "gpdf.pdf"
#set xlabel "α"; set ylabel "β"
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y"
plot sin(x)
```

When I open the PDF and its document property shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the terminal's `font` option you must select a font which is available as Type1 on your system (and reachable for libpango). Here, on Windows, I could use "Univers LT 55", which is the only Type1 font I have installed at the moment:

```
set term pdfcairo font "Univers LT 55"
set output "gpdf.pdf"
set xlabel "x"; set ylabel "y"
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

But then you'll most probably run into problems when using utf-8 encoding. What's the actual problem you're having with ghostscript and CID fonts?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I find my installed type-1 fonts? The problem I am having with gs is that it can not convert PDF to EPS with embeded CID fonts. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609400/ghostscript-convert-pdf-to-eps-with-embeded-font-rather-than-outlined-curve.

Comment: I do not want to use gnuplot to generate eps directly, as eps files are very inconvenient to view, process, etc.

Comment: So what do you need the eps for if pdf is much more comfortable for you? If you need the eps only as end product for whatever processing, you could try using the `pdfcairo` terminal for your normal work and then the `epscairo` terminal for the terminal step (don't know if and how those terminals actually may differ).

Comment: I need eps because many journals ask for them. There are lots of problems when converting PDF to EPS. Do you why people still ask for eps instead of PDF? It is indeed weird. The journals who ask for EPS have to convert eps to pdf anyway. Can not really understand their logic.

Comment: Many journals do not accept PDF figures and ask for EPS!

Comment: I just had a look, using `epscairo` and `pdfcairo` looks quite promising to me, judging from the output of the `test` command. Almost no differences.

Comment: That is excellent! Another thing I spotted is that, when you use epscairo to produce a eps and then convert eps to pdf using ghostscript, the pdf will not use CID fonts. However, when you use pdfcairo, the pdf will definitely use CID fonts (either type-1 or true type).